# Python default values for parameters in delegated function calls

Tags: python, default-value, optional-parameters, delegation

There is a function with a default value for a parameter:

```
def g(y, z = "default"):
    print  y, z
```

I want to call this function from a function "f", that among others should also contain a parameter "z", which shall be optional, i. e. the user of "f" should be able to call "f" with or without providing a value for "z". If he calls "f" without passing "z" in the argument list, "f" should call "g" so that the default value for "z" is used in the end. The value used as the default value (in this example "default") should occur only once in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your main goal is to make sure `"default"` only occurs once in the code.

```
def g(y, z = None):
    if z is None:
        z = "default"
    print y, z

def f(y, z = None):
    g(y, z)
```

Comment: That seems to work in practice. The case that f(1, None) shall mean something else than f(1) might be too academic.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`**kwargs`](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another):

```
def f(**kwargs):
    g("fixed-y", **kwargs)

f() # prints "fixed-y default"
f(z='mushroom') # prints "fixed-y mushroom"
```

Comment: What if "f" looks like this:
    def f(a, b, w, z):
        h(..., w)
        g(..., z)
i. e. there are multiple parameters "w" and "z" with this problem. "w" shall be passed to another function "h" and "z" shall be passed to "g". So I cannot handle both together in **kwargs.

Comment: You'll have to do some more work, but there's nothing to stop you from pulling the input `kwargs` into different pieces. Alternatively, if you know the order they're coming in, you can use `*args` positional arguments instead. `h(a, args[0]); g(b, args[1])` or whatever.